# Insufficient rights - how to check what rights a command expects?

Tags: c#, .net, clojure, clr

I am a .net newbie. I was trying to build this particular CLR project - http://github.com/richhickey/clojure-clr. I received the following error.

```
C:\sriram\work\clojure\clojure-clr\Clojure\Clojure.Compile\bin\Debug\Clojure.Compile.exe clojure.core clojure.set clojure.zip clojure.main clojure.walk clojure.stacktrace clojure.template clojure.test clojure.test.tap clojure.test.junit Access is denied.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(3397,13): error MSB3075: The command "C:\sriram\work\clojure\clojure-clr\Clojure\Clojure.Compile\bin\Debug\Clojure.Compile.exe clojure.core clojure.set clojure.zip clojure.main clojure.walk clojure.stacktrace clojure.template clojure.test clojure.test.tap clojure.test.junit" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.

Done building project "Clojure.Compile.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

It says 'Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command'. How to check what rights are begin expected ?

OS is Windows 7 Home Premium
Visual Studio edition is 2008 Professional SP1
.Net Version is 3.5

Answer (score 2):

For VisualStudio2010 post build registration event faild because of insufficient permission
Do as below:

-Click on Start->All Programs->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

-Right click on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

-Click on Run As...

-Un chcek protect my computer and data from unauthorized program activity 
   and click OK, it will open VisualStudio2010

-Open your (for example ATL project)project and run, it will compile and  do the successful registration

Answer (score 1):

Note that some commands may work or not depending on the arguments of the command.
Even simple copy may work if you have write privilege to the target folder and fail when you don't have the privilege to write.

On win 7 and Vista machines problem is that you need to run Visual Studio with elevated privileges even if you are admin on the machine.
To do that right click on Visual Studio in the start menu and choose "Run as administrator".

Comment: I have ran development in VS (c++, C#, WPF,WCF,ASP) on a user account without admin rights on XP,Vista,Win7 without problems. 
I do have an admin command prompt where I can run simple things like regasm, installutil etc.

Comment: There's no question that run VS without admin rights. The problem is when a build is doing something that require an admin rights such as calling gacinstall etc.